# Blender 2.80 not working on AMD Radeon HD 6470M GPU

Tags: error, opengl

I'm not able to open Blender 2.80, it tells me that it requires OpenGL 3.3 Core

[image: Unsupported Graphics card message]

So i wanted to make sure that the problem is from my GPU and not from blender itself,

so i wrote a simple OpenGL application using OpenGL 3.3 core profile that renders a simple textured cube, and also check my GPU's driver supported OpenGL version

and here is the result

[image: Cube render using OpenGL 3.3]

it looks just fine to me.

it's also not just a static render, you can move around that little cube, and OpenGL didn't complain about my GPU not supporting GL 3.3

i'm i missing something here?

is the problem from my GPU, or is it a bug in blender itself (which is likely since it's just a beta release)

and how to fix it (if possible, of course).

Edit: It's working when i run it in *640 x 480* Resolution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by:

**1)** Updating my driver to the latest available version (i should have done so from the beginning).

**2)** Downloaded **opengl32.dll** file from [here](http://www.dlldownloader.com/opengl32-dll/) and copied it to the blender's root directory.

Now Blender 2.8 is working without any issues :)